# datagrid access from another form

Tags: c#

I have datagridview in form1. How can I access datagridview from form2.

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
          string sql1 = "insert into Car (plate, color, [year], model) values ('"+tplate.Text+"','"+tcolor.Text+"',"+tyear.Text+",'"+tmodel.Text+"')";            
          string sql2 = "select * from Car";
            try
            {
                int res = CarDatabase.executeOthers(sql1);
                if(res >0){
                    DataTable dt = CarDatabase.executeSelect(sql2);
                    mainframe.Dgv.DataSource = dt;                
                    MessageBox.Show("New Car is added");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
  }
```

here mainframe.Dgv is in the first form

but I cannot access like that Form1.dataGridView why :S

Comment: Does Form1 have a reference to Form2? If not, can it? If not, does some other form or object have references to Form1 and Form2?

Comment: in my example i have two forms.In above an example from the net. How can i access datagridview in form1 from form2 :S

Comment: Does Form2 get opened by Form1?

Comment: yeah Form2 f = new Form2();
            f.Visible = true; this is the button click event in form1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Form2:

```
public DataGridView Dgv { get; set; }
```

In Form1:

```
Form2 f = new Form2();
f.Dgv = mainframe.Dgv;
```

In Form2 access its own Dgv propety.

Answer (score 4):

You need a reference to the actual `Form` in order to access its members.  (And those members will need to be `public`.)

Just calling something like this:

```
Form1.dataGridView
```

won't work because `Form1` is just a type, it's not a reference to an instantiated object in memory.  That's how you'd reference `static` members, which isn't the case here.  The `DataGridView` is an instance member.  So you need a reference to the *instance* of `Form1`.  Something more like:

```
firstForm.dgv
```

where `firstForm` is a variable on `Form2` (or passed into the method as an argument from `Form1`, where the argument would just be `this`, etc.) and `dgv` is the public member on `Form1` which represents the `DataGridView`.

Something like this:

```
public class Form1
{
    public DataGridView DGV { get; set; }

    private void DoSomething()
    {
        var anotherForm = new Form2();
        anotherForm.DoSomethingElse(this);
    }
}

public class Form2
{
    public void DoSomethingElse(Form1 firstForm)
    {
        var data = firstForm.DGV.DataSource;
    }
}
```

Note that I left out a lot of WinForms stuff here.  That's intentional.  This is just to demonstrate the concept at the code level.  What the forms inherit from, how they're instantiated, how they're held in memory, that's all another concern.

How you set this up is up to you.  I'm not well versed in WinForms development, but I imagine there are better ways to accomplish this.  In order to determine that, though, we'd need to know *why* `Form2` needs to access `Form1`'s `DataGridView`.  It's likely that, instead, they should both access a shared back-end resource.  Maybe something more like this:

```
public class Form1
{
    private DataGridView dgv { get; set; }

    private void LoadMyData()
    {
        dgv.DataSource = GlobalDataSources.SomeDataSource;
    }

    private void DoSomething()
    {
        var anotherForm = new Form2();
        anotherForm.DoSomethingElse();
    }
}

public class Form2
{
    public void DoSomethingElse()
    {
        var data = GlobalDataSources.SomeDataSource;
    }
}

public class GlobalDataSources
{
    private static SomeDataSourceType _someDataSource;
    public static SomeDataSourceType SomeDataSource
    {
        get
        {
            if (_someDataSource == null)
            {
                // populate the data source
            }
            return _someDataSource;
        }
    }
}
```

As always, there are many ways to do it.  But the basic idea is that, instead of accessing each other and creating all kinds of cross-dependencies, your front-end forms access shared back-end resources and the dependency chain just flows in that one direction.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the dataGridView field/property "public" or "internal".  Choose public if you're a beginner like it sounds.