# How to add row to datagridview situated on another form

Tags: c#, datagridview, addition, rows

i have two form applictaion. and i have datagrid with three string columns on the "MainForm".
the destination of the second form is to add rows to this datagrid with some parametres such as text of the 1,2 and 3 columnns

this code works

```
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  dgvTasks.Rows.Add("s1", "s2", "s3");
}
```

**but when i drop this code to another form it doesn't work**

```
//"MainForm"
public void addRowToDataGridView(string type, string title, string time)
{
  dgvTasks.Rows.Add(type, title, time);
}

//"ParametersForm"
public static MainForm fm = new MainForm();
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  fm.addRowToDataGridView("s1", "s2", "s3");
}
```

no errors. just silent and rows don't add.
can smb help me?

Comment: I'm not very clear on what your situation is, where the gridview is and what your forms aim to do.

Comment: it depends on where code is situated/ if code and datagrid - on the same form it works. but after puting code to another form it's stop working

Comment: the aim of the second form is to add rows. the datagrid situated on the first form. can you tell me how can i do it?

Comment: What your doing wrong is ==> `MainForm fm = new MainForm();`  You need to access the **instance** of the main form expose the datagrid from there.

Comment: im looked for how can i access to the datagrid situated on another form. result was public static MainForm fm = new MainForm(); do you know other way to do it?

Comment: ok, now my destination is to know how to create instance of the main form.i didnt add datatgrid programmatically. i just droped it to the form and made pubic modifiers.
may i count on detailed answer?

Comment: done! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595667/datagird-access-from-another-form helped answer #1. best regards!

Answer (score 2):

MainForm fm = new MainForm();

This way , You created another MainForm when you create instance object for MainForm.

You should attain active  MainForm. So you should hold the active MainForm instance.

```
//"MainForm"

public static MainForm MainFormRef { get; private set; }
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MainFormRef = this;
}

public void addRowToDataGridView(string type, string title, string time)
{
  dgvTasks.Rows.Add(type, title, time);
}


//"ParametersForm"
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var fm = MainForm.MainFormRef;
  fm.addRowToDataGridView("s1", "s2", "s3");
}
```

Comment: May I just ask if that public static MainForm MainFormRef gets disposed when MainForm is closed?

Comment: So it remains even after MainForm is closed and not needed anymore?

Comment: I'm sorry, I could not complete my comment. All of it: No, It is not disposed. MainFormRef will keep the MainForm memory address. In this way, you can create a new MainForm using MainFormRef.  
Furthermore, MainForm is not cleared from memory because MainForm is static until the application or thr Form1 are closed.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, i can suggest you such an answer

Make a property 'setter' in MainForm of any type 
(Ex: a

```
//here is your MainForm
{
    public List<MyGVContent> SetColumnHead
    {
           set
           {
                  //here call your method to whom give 'value' as parameter
                  //attention, that in value contains items with Type, Title, Time
                  addRowToDataGridView();
           }
    }
    //which will update your 'dgvTasks' gridview
) 

//here is your Parameters Form
{
    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //here call the property to whom send parameters
        this.MainForm.SetColumnHead = ...
    }
}

//where 
public sealed class MyGVContent
{
    string Type
    {
        get; set;
    }

    string Title
    {
        get; set;
    }

    string Time
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

Good luck.