# Datagridview not loading from another class

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview, controls

I have dll add-in for Solidworks. Within it I'm using activeX control which is basic control that have buttons and datagridview on it. I'm generating some data in solidowkorks which I would like to add to datagridview. So far for adding I was using a button on control and it works fine.

My problem is that I want to add it from solidworks button. 
It is a different class so I declared new instance of control and call it that way. I created a sub that is a copy of buttton click sub used for loading information to datagridview. This sub is being fired as I tested it with debug.print and also variables in control get proper values.

My problem is that datagridview is not adding these values.

If I call same sub from within control it works fine. I tried changing declaration of datagridview from friend to public with no success. 
The only idea I have to make datagridview public shared which worked, but I don't want to go that way for many reasons.

Does anybody have an idea what could be causing this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm having trouble trying to understand your issue. Do you just want to access a datagridview from some other class?

Comment: Can you post some sort of visual representation of what you trying to do?

Comment: I had a problem adding rows to datagridview from another class. I was trying to create new instance of class that datagridview belonged to but background processes worked fine but there was no change on the screen. When i learned more what creating new instance does exactly I understood where the problem was. I used  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477151/how-to-add-row-to-datagridview-situated-on-another-form) example to create vb.net solution.Thanks for responses