# Display query results in dataGridView of another form

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, datagridview

I am working with a local DB created in Access which I added as a DataSource to my C# project. I have 2 forms: `RoomSelect` and `RoomActiveSession`.

RoomSelect contains of a listbox with 4 values (room numbers) and a button. User selects the room number, clicks OK, and should be redirected to `RoomActiveSession` form, where the active sessions for the given room number should be displayed in DGV.

RoomActiveSession contains of dataGridView to display the results.

My question is: How can I properly access DGV from `RoomSelect` to display the result of my query?

`RoomSelect` code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AutoReg
{
    public partial class RoomSelect : Form
    {

        DataTable queryResult = new DataTable();
        public string RoomID;
        RoomActiveSession RoomActiveSessionForm = new RoomActiveSession();

        public RoomSelect()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            switch (listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())
            {
                case "MB0302":
                    RoomID = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                    RoomActiveSessionForm.ShowDialog();
                    roomQuery();
                    break;
                case "MC1001":
                    RoomID = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                    RoomActiveSessionForm.ShowDialog();
                    roomQuery();
                    break;
                case "MC3203":
                    RoomID = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                    RoomActiveSessionForm.ShowDialog();
                    roomQuery();
                    break;
                case "MC3204":
                    RoomID = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                    RoomActiveSessionForm.ShowDialog();
                    roomQuery();
                    break;

            }
        }

        public void roomQuery()
        {
            string ConnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Kacper\\Desktop\\AutoReg\\AutoReg\\AutoReg.accdb;";

            OleDbConnection MyConn = new OleDbConnection(ConnStr);
            MyConn.Open();

            //SQL query that todays sessions for the given roomID
            string query = @"SELECT SessionID, SemesterA, SemesterB, RoomID, SessionDate, SessionTimeStart, SessionTimeEnd" +
               " FROM [Session] " +
               " WHERE RoomID = @RoomID " +
               " AND SessionDate = Date() ";

            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, MyConn);

            command.Parameters.Add("RoomID", OleDbType.Char).Value = RoomID;


            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);

            adapter.Fill(queryResult);

            if (queryResult.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No active sessions today for the given room number");
                MyConn.Close();
            }
            else
            {

                RoomActiveSession.dataGridView1.DataSource = queryResult;
                MyConn.Close();
            }


        }

    }
}
```

I receive an error on the line: `RoomActiveSession.dataGridView1.DataSource = queryResult;`

```
'AutoReg.RoomActiveSession.dataGridView1' is inaccessible due to its protection level   C:\Users\Kacper\Desktop\AutoReg\AutoReg\RoomSelect.cs
```

According to this post [datagird access from another form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595667/datagird-access-from-another-form) I should create get,set properties for DGV in `RoomActiveSession`, but I'm not sure how to do it (should I modify code in the `RoomActiveSession` designer?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `dataGridView1` modifier to `public`. You can select that `dataGridView1` and set the `Modifiers` in `Properties` window.

To create property to get access to your `dataGridView1`, do this: (I think you just need to get access, don't allow to modify it):

```
public class RoomActiveSession : Form {
   //.....
   public DataGridView Grid {
      get { return dataGridView1; }
   }
}
//you can keep your dataGridView1 modifier as private
```

You can also define some public method to do some thing with your `dataGridView1`, such as `SetDataSource`:

```
public void SetDataSouce(object source){
    dataGridView1.DataSource = source;
}
```

There are many many ways to interact with your `dataGridView1` from outside the class `RoomActiveSession`.

Comment: Thank you for extensive answer!